# How to assign an image_message to a transformation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dear TF community.

I am publishing two image messages, "depth_image" and "infared_image" from two cameras. My goal is to register the depth image on the ir img.
I have made the external calibration, and do publish it using the static_transform_publisher.
The internal calibration parameters are published from the camera nodes.
I am visualizing the images in rviz, and do see the two frames I created (depth_camera and ir_camera). Now if I switch in rviz between the frames, nothing happens to the images.
My guess is, that I haven't assigned the frames to the cameras.

So... If my guess is right, how would I assign a frame to a camera node?
Or if not, do you maybe have an idea what is missing for the registration process?

Thanks,
Josh.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390570/how-to-assign-an-image_message-to-a-transformation/) by [max_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/89316/max_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-11-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-12**:
Hi @max_ros take a look at prior question: https://answers.ros.org/question/244900/easiest-way-to-set-2-cameras-relative-transformation/

Yes you will need to assign transform for each camera

**Comment by [max_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/89316/max_ros/) on 2021-12-22**:
Hi @osilva. Thanks.
I followed the hints in the answer you linked and am now on the following status:

- all images are published with their corresponding frame_id
- The transformation between the frames is published as static transform
- In rviz, when opening tf, there are no errors or warnings as all transformations are known.
- Really I have two cameras (ir camera and realsense d435) but three images, as thre realsenes camera is an RGB-D camera.

However I still haven't archieved my goal, which is to overlay the ir_image on the rgb image (or on the pointcloud, doesn't matter).
Do you have a hint for me how to archive this? Do i need to apply the tranfsormations to the images manually? (I though rviz takes care of that for me?).

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-22**:
Hi @max_ros check if this is what you are trying to do: https://answers.ros.org/question/321701/is-it-possible-to-overlay-a-2d-image-over-a-pointcloud-in-rviz2/

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-22**:
Settings: https://github.com/robogeekcanada/STEMClub/blob/master/62DF6B13-2E82-417F-B9A4-556659A6BA56.png

**Comment by [max_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/89316/max_ros/) on 2021-12-28**:
Hi @osilva - yes this was again a very good hint, thanks!

However I still haven't archieved my goal :-D
I now use the depth_image_proc register node, which is supposed to map my depth map on my infrared image. From there on I could also project both on a pointcloud.
This in general works fine, except that I only do receive black images. So I strongly guess something is wrong with my calibration. However I do have troubles to debug this.
Do you by chance also have a hint how to proceed (is is the internal calibration of the infrared camera, is it the external calibration, ...)?

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-28**:
Hi @max_ros I suggest we wrap this question with a partial answer based on the progress you made so far. Document your effort so others may benefit and start a new question with the new things that are still unresolved. This way more people will have visibility to help as well. Also with a new question, you could more pictures to help visualize what you are dealing with.

**Comment by [max_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/89316/max_ros/) on 2021-12-29**:
@osilva : [new question](https://answers.ros.org/question/393513/registering-depth-image-on-different-image-size/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, as @osilva suggested, here a summary how I solved it:

I have the following topics published:

- depth/image_raw
- depth/camera_info    (conatining the internal calbiration parameter and the frame id of the depth camera)
- ir/camera_info   (conatining the internal calbiration parameter and the frame id of the ir camera)
- tf2 static tranform between the two frames ids.

Using [depth_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc) package regsiter, I can now map the depth data in the ir frame. My launch file looks like this:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="namespace_ir" default="gas_camera"/>
  <arg name="namespace_vis" default="realsense"/>
  
  
  <!-- gas_cam --> 
  <include file="$(find gas_cam)/launch/gas_cam.launch"> 
        <arg name="namespace" value="$(arg namespace_ir)" />
   </include>  
  
  <!-- realsense --> 
    <include file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/rs_camera.launch"  ns="$(arg namespace_vis)"> 
        <arg name="filters" value="pointcloud" />
        <arg name="tf_prefix" value="rs" />
   </include>
  
  
  <!-- tf2 -->   
    <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="rs_2_ir" args="-0.062249 -0.083060 0.006821 0.00465763 0.052355 0.02046292  rs_link ir_kam_frame" />
 
    
  <!-- stereo proc for image registration -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" args="manager" />
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet1" args="load depth_image_proc/register nodelet_manager">
        <remap from="depth/camera_info" to="/$(arg namespace_vis)/camera/depth/camera_info"/>
        <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/$(arg namespace_ir)/camera_info"/>
        <remap from="depth/image_rect" to="/$(arg namespace_vis)/camera/depth/image_rect_raw"/>
    </node>
    
    <!-- RVIZ -->
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find gas_cam)/rviz/default_visualization.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [max_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/89316/max_ros/) with karma: 36 on 2021-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1